# how to provide angular material design font size specification given in SP in CSS

Tags: material-design, angular-material

As given [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-interaction)

Material design specification says use fontsize as '13sp' for table header..

How to specify sp in CSS.

Should I convert sp to pixel as given [here](http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/) and then set it for e.g.

```
.fontClass
{
  font-size:10px.
}
```

Is it corect?

Comment: http://materialdesignblog.com/material-design-typeface-in-css/